# Easy switching languages?

Tags: launcher, localization, user-interface

A tablet will be used by someone who reads (only) Chinese (PRC). I only read English. In order to help her accomplish things, install apps, and generally maintain the tablet, I need to switch language settings.

Since I can’t read the settings menu, dialog boxes, etc. and she is a non-technical user, I want some icon on the Home screen that will toggle settings. It doesn’t matter if it’s an app or a widget, but the idea is that once situated on the Launcher screen then anyone can easily toggle languages without having to understand the currently set language.

Can someone point me to something like that?

Answer (score 2):

I found this app to be very easy to use and basically works with just two taps. It's called [Change Lanuage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.examobile.changelanguage) and can be found officially from the play store. Then only setback is that you'll only be able to change languages based on languages installed on the phone. Which means if you don't have chinese dictionary and language pack on your phone you'll have to download it through the phone settings page first. Add the app widget to the home screen and you'll be able to change in less than 5 seconds.

Comment: That’s no drawback… I assumed the languages would be available.

Comment: It appears to be just a shortcut to the language setting. That helps with finding the settings when in a different language, assuming you can still figure out that page.  I’d still like to find a toggle that knows the two I’ve configured.